# Developer Application not showing requests

Tags: facebook

My developer application shows the following message : 
"You have 2 pending developer requests. View all. "

But when i click "View all" nothing happens...

This way i cannot be added to any role of any application

Answer (score 3):

access the link http://www.facebook.com/reqs.php directly
in this page, you should be able to see all the oustanding requests

Comment: No, that page doesn't show me anything... no requests appear here...:(

Comment: I just ran into this problem, and this solution worked for me. Thanks, Eddy.